# My query is return not table values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have FinancialCompliances and Compliance tables. Below my query work flow is get one latest row .The problem is i have empty values in table because i deleted all rows in my table .But my below query is return one old rows .

```
var Compliance = (from c in datamodel.Compliances
                              join f in datamodel.FinancialCompliances on c.ComplianceId equals f.ComplianceId
                              where (c.VerifierId == userId || c.OwnerId == userId || c.UserId == userId) && (f.ComplianceId == c.ComplianceId)
                              orderby (f.AddedDate)
                              select f);

            financialCompliance = Compliance.ToList().LastOrDefault();
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You're saying the query above shows rows that have been deleted?  Perhaps whatever transaction deleted the rows has not yet been committed, or perhaps this data is somehow being cached by the Entity Framework?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to with your `Where` clause, what is different and or unique about that returned record. what can you notice about the other records where you can actually determine uniqueness to add to your conditional could you add a `Deleted Flag` to the table or in a query and do the `Linq` qury based on that flag along with the `userId`

Comment: Is the line in the where clause "&& (f.ComplianceId == c.ComplianceId)" - really necessary since you are already doing the join on the ComplianceId above the where clause?

Comment: @MikeChristensen okay .How can i remove catch in EF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may be deleting your objects in the datamodel instance but not saving the changes and resetting the datamodel, thereby keeping the old records still in the context even if they aren't in the database. To be safe, try using a new context for this query.

Also, you may want to consider modifying the query to order the results decending and then selecting the top one rather than ordering them ascending and taking only the last one:

```
var Compliance = (from c in datamodel.Compliances
                  join f in datamodel.FinancialCompliances on c.ComplianceId equals f.ComplianceId
                  where (c.VerifierId == userId || c.OwnerId == userId || c.UserId == userId) && (f.ComplianceId == c.ComplianceId)
                  orderby (f.AddedDate) descending
                  select f);

financialCompliance = Compliance.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the rows are being deleted in the database and that you are using a new datamodel instance for this query?

Comment: Any way .next time i don't delete table rows . It's okay .leave it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps lastordefalt are sending the default value. Could you please confirm that you actually have real data in your object that is returned? I doubt that would be the case.

Comment: I have seen this with the Oracle DBMS using Toad.  You will no longer see the effected data.. however it still exists and is not modified... until a rollback or commit is executed of course!

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem with your code is that you are calling ToList() before LastOrDefault(). This will cause your code to load all data from your storage into your application and context, and then from the result retrieving the last object. I suspect that this may cause some problems.

Try to skip your .ToList() and call LastOrDefault() directly.